# How can I make the map draggable?

Tags: android, layout

I have a library that draw map automatically, all I just do is extends the library and it will draw a map for me. Now the problem is when I use sliding panel

```
mMenuLayout.addView(menu);
mMenuLayout.addView(frame);
addContentView(mMenuLayout, fp);
```

mMenuLayout is a sliding panel,
menu is layout contains ListView,
frame is layout contains Buttons

The sliding panel,which contains 2 layout will be in front of the map (the map become background) and I can't drag map anymore.

Comment: can you please be more specific with images so that we can solve...thx

Comment: Here is the xml
https://app.box.com/s/z1styde57vu4ld4k05uj4jfwke6un8od
Here are the pics:
http://postimg.org/image/id21kf7fz/
http://s28.postimg.org/suoim8zyl/Untitled2.jpg

Comment: The map will be draw at LinearLayout (id = map_view). But as you can see, when I add it to slidingpanel, it will be blank like that.